# Не получается раскрыть список и удерживать его открытым до потери фокуса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть корзина, которая раскрывает список по наведению. У меня проблема сделать так, чтобы по наведению на корзину отображался список и исчезал только, если отвести мышку от фокуса. Получается сделать либо прышающий список при наведении на корзину, либо только открытое кго состояние без сворачивания. Как сделать все правильно?

[Фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/gmf2jb6p/)

```js
$(".basket").hover(function() {
  $('.mini-cart').show();
}, function() {
  if ($('.basket-cart').is(':hover') !== true) {
    $('.mini-cart').hide();
  }
  //$('.mini-cart').hide();
});
```

```css
.mini-cart {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 21px 46px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basket-wrapper">
  <div class="basket basket-cart">
    <img class="basket-img" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180628/elp/kisspng-shopping-cart-online-shopping-computer-icons-thee-5b352999e4eea1.7573866015302107139377.jpg" width="53" height="47">
  </div>
  <div class="mini-cart basket-cart">
    <h3>Список</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Позиция 1</li>
      <li>Позиция 2</li>
      <li>Позиция 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем так все усложнять?

```js
$(".basket, .mini-cart").hover(function() {
  $('.mini-cart').toggle();
});
```

```css
.mini-cart {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px 21px 46px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basket-wrapper">
  <div class="basket basket-cart">
    <img class="basket-img" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180628/elp/kisspng-shopping-cart-online-shopping-computer-icons-thee-5b352999e4eea1.7573866015302107139377.jpg" width="53" height="47">
  </div>
  <div class="mini-cart basket-cart">
    <h3>Список</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Позиция 1</li>
      <li>Позиция 2</li>
      <li>Позиция 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Тут вообще можно без JS обойтись

```css
.mini-cart {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px 21px 46px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.basket:hover + .mini-cart, .mini-cart:hover
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basket-wrapper">
  <div class="basket basket-cart">
    <img class="basket-img" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180628/elp/kisspng-shopping-cart-online-shopping-computer-icons-thee-5b352999e4eea1.7573866015302107139377.jpg" width="53" height="47">
  </div>
  <div class="mini-cart basket-cart">
    <h3>Список</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Позиция 1</li>
      <li>Позиция 2</li>
      <li>Позиция 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Убирай js, ты этим только усложняешь. А CSS такой:

```
.basket {
  width: 49px;
  height: 49px;
}

.mini-cart {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 21px 46px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.basket:hover + .mini-cart {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: результата не вижу - список по прежнему от мышки убегает.. http://jsfiddle.net/e5m18xha/2/

Answer (score 1):

Не называйте это фокусом.

```js
$(".basket").hover(function() {
  $('.mini-cart').show();
}, function() {
  //if ($('.basket-cart').is(':hover') !== true) {
  //  $('.mini-cart').hide();
  //}
  $('.mini-cart').hide();
});
```

```css
.mini-cart {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 21px 46px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basket-wrapper">
  <div class="basket basket-cart">
    <img class="basket-img" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180628/elp/kisspng-shopping-cart-online-shopping-computer-icons-thee-5b352999e4eea1.7573866015302107139377.jpg" width="53" height="47">
    <div class="mini-cart basket-cart">
      <h3>Список</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Позиция 1</li>
        <li>Позиция 2</li>
        <li>Позиция 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вот объясните мне, пожалуйста, почему в фидле у меня постоянно список убегает? Код как у вас или я что-то упускаю?
http://jsfiddle.net/gmf2jb6p/21/
И точно такое же поведение на сайте..

Comment: @Вася я внес `mini-cart` внутрь `basket` - в разметке

Comment: понял. А если не вносить? У меня `basket` просто имеет размеры 145 на 145 и причем `dispaly:flex`, а список гораздо больший и не помещается внутри баскета. что тогда? Как не меняя разметки получить результат?

Comment: @Вася Так вроде пара решений предложена в других ответах. Напишите, почему они не устраивают.